# Inheriting a MainWindow class from QMainWindow and Ui_MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qmainwindow

**I am learning Qt, Qt 5. When I start Qt Creator and create a project with ALL the default settings, I get these 2 files generated, (I am excluding main.cpp and the .pro file)**

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

---

**Now, I prefer to do it this way,**

**my_mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, private Ui_MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

**my_mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "my_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :   QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

---

**Here are the main differences between my code and Qt Creator's code:**

1. No `namespace Ui` in my code. (Could anyone explain me the use of this namespace here ?)
2. I inherit the `MainWindow` class from both `QMainWindow` and `Ui_MainWindow` whereas the Qt Creator's code inherits it only from the `QMainWindow` class.

My question is, is there ANY disadvantage of using my approach or is there any advantage of using the Qt Creator's approach ? Please give a detailed answer.

Comment: Does your project actually compile?

Comment: Yes, both the versions work as expected. Why ?

Comment: @Rage In the Qt 4 days the meta object compiler (MOC) did not like multiple inheritance with QObjects or any derived classes.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky Really ? Why ?

Comment: @Rage Possibly because of the memory layout in the class. Possibly because inheriting from two classes derived from `QObjects` doesn't work. It also didn't like virtual inheritance. I do not know why. But it didn't work.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky Well, but I it works just **FINE** with Qt 5.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. An advantage of the namespace is that it prevents naming clashes. All the automatically generated names from QtDesigner stay in their own namespace.
2. An advantage of making the Ui class a member, instead of using multiple inheritance, is that the Ui class only needs to be forward-declarded in the header. In your code, you have a `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"`, and that in turn drags in a lot of includes from QtWidgets like `<QLabel>`, `<QPushButton>` etc. This decreases compilation speed significantly, as everyone who includes `mainwindow.h` now also includes those QtWidgets includes. When using the Ui class as a member and forward-declaring it, all these includes only need to be compiled when compiling `mainwindow.cpp`, but not when including `mainwindow.h` from somewhere else.